# Fetch data from an api in useEffect or in event handler directly in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How a fetch should be performed in react hooks?
Among these two code snippets, which one is called a best practice or a best react pattern to perform a fetch?

This example is using `useEffect` to perform a `fetch` operation.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) return;
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${query}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data.items);
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [loading, query]);

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Search Github Repo.</h1>
      <h3>Implementation One</h3>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={query}
          onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {!loading &&
        data.map(repo => (
          <div key={repo.id}>
            <h4>{repo.name}</h4>
            <p>{repo.description}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This example is using the `onClick` event handler to perform a `fetch` operation.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${query}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data.items);
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Search Github Repo.</h1>
      <h3>Implementation Two</h3>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={query}
          onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {!loading &&
        data.map(repo => (
          <div key={repo.id}>
            <h4>{repo.name}</h4>
            <p>{repo.description}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Running example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-qe3l5)

Comment: I don't understand the question? it depends entirely on how your application requires. if you need the data on load use `useEffect` for hooks or `componentDidMount` for classes. if you only need it on button click then call it when you click a button like you have done

Comment: As per my understanding in your case, you should use `useEffect`, because with this you always have correct query state

Comment: @RedBaron, Is it good to perform actions after the UI state has been changed on performing an action. As that would be a reactive way to do it or it is not?

Comment: you should use Shubham's answer, that makes sense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depend on your usecase as to which method you should take

fetching data in `useEffect` is useful in following scenarios

- Fetching data during some lifecycles like initial render
- Fetching data when some prop changes
- fetching data in an interval but setting up a subscription or `setInterval`

Fetching data in handler is useful in below scenario

- Based on a user interaction such as search button click, search input change

Since your case is a based on a use interaction its better and more controlled to actually call the API in a handler instead of a `useEffect` hook

Comment: Isn't `fetch` is an effect which should be placed in an `useEffect` hook and be more reactive on change of loading state?

Comment: An effect is something that occurs as a result of change, and fetch is a result of change in input but would you write a fetch request in componentDidUpdate for a search functionality. Similar argument goes here.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should go with the hooks implementation. It's recommended in the React docs for performing side effects:

> Data fetching, setting up a subscription, and manually changing the DOM in React components are all examples of side effects. Whether or not you’re used to calling these operations “side effects” (or just “effects”), you’ve likely performed them in your components before.
> ([link to the quote](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html))

There is one more consideration to think about. In your hook implementation:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) return;
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${query}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data.items);
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [loading, query]);
```

you used an optimization. You're passing `[loading, query]` into your hook, which means the function will run only when one of those values change. In your second implementation you will have your fetch running on every single input change

[Here's a link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) to the React docs about this aspect of hooks.

Comment: You could also optimize by wrapping the input change with a debounce or something. It's not like we didn't have this issue before Hooks :)